# making animation with matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to make animated gif using matplotlib. I found simple example here : https://tomroelandts.com/articles/how-to-create-animated-gifs-with-python 
And now i am trying to adapt it to my problem. Below is the code i worked out :

```
from __future__ import division
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

class AnimatedGif:
    def __init__(self,radius = 10):
        ############################################################
        self.fig = plt.figure(frameon=False,figsize=(12,10))
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
        ax = Axes3D(self.fig)
        ax.set_xlim((-.7*radius,.7*radius))
        ax.set_ylim((-.7*radius,.7*radius))
        ax.set_zlim((0*radius,1.4*radius))
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.xaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('black')
        ax.yaxis.pane.set_edgecolor('black')
        ax.xaxis.pane.fill = False
        ax.yaxis.pane.fill = False
        ax.zaxis.pane.fill = False
        self.images = []
    ####################################################################
    def add(self,step, area='',azim = 0, elev = 7,color = 'k',numOfLayer = 10,Length = 1.,alpha = 0.8,ids = False):
        from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
        import matplotlib as mpl
        from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
        from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
        ################################################
        ax = self.fig.gca()
        verts = [zip([step*0.5+0.,5,1.,2,1,2],[0.,3,2.,2,1,2],[0.,9,3.,2,1,2])]
        pc = Poly3DCollection(verts,alpha = alpha,linewidths=1, facecolor = color)
        pc.set_edgecolor('k')
        ax.add_collection3d(pc)
        ax.view_init(azim = azim,elev=elev)
        plt_im = ax
        self.images.append([plt_im])
    ####################################################################
    def save(self, filename):
        animation = anim.ArtistAnimation(self.fig, self.images)
        print animation
        animation.save(filename, writer='imagemagick', fps=1)
##################################################################
endStep = 100
stepsize = 5
##################################################################
animated_gif = AnimatedGif()
step = 0 
area = 0 
animated_gif.add(step,area=str(area))
images = []
for step in range(stepsize+1, endStep,stepsize):
    area = 10
    animated_gif.add(step, area=str(area))

animated_gif.save('cell-animated1.gif')
```

I need to use Poly3DCollection to make bunch of polygons on 3d and they move with timestep. Here I just made a simple case with polygon moving in x-axis with step. But there is no output. The output is just blank white.

---

My confusion mainly came from lack of good examples on use of `ArtistAnimation`. On [the documentation for it](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation), `artists` argument is mentioned as "Each list entry a collection of artists that represent what needs to be enabled on each frame. These will be disabled for other frames.". However, I did not get what is exactly expected. I made the `Poly3DCollection` but again just passing it by adding it to the `self.images` was not enough as it needed to be added to the `axes` too (`ax.add_collection(pc)`) in the end. I figured directly images needed to be added so tried adding the `pc` to the `collection` and append the `ax` to the `self.images`, which was completely wrong in the end.

Also most of the error I got was :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bd3b8eac5524> in <module>()
     56     animated_gif.add(step, area=str(area))
     57 
---> 58 animated_gif.save('cell-animated1.gif')

<ipython-input-1-bd3b8eac5524> in save(self, filename)
     42         animation = anim.ArtistAnimation(self.fig, self.images)
     43         print animation
---> 44         animation.save(filename, writer='imagemagick', fps=4)
     45 ##################################################################
     46 endStep = 100

/Users/name/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.pyc in save(self, filename, writer, fps, dpi, codec, bitrate, extra_args, metadata, extra_anim, savefig_kwargs)
   1055                 for anim in all_anim:
   1056                     # Clear the initial frame
-> 1057                     anim._init_draw()
   1058                 for data in zip(*[a.new_saved_frame_seq()
   1059                                   for a in all_anim]):

/Users/name/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.pyc in _init_draw(self)
   1374         # Flush the needed figures
   1375         for fig in figs:
-> 1376             fig.canvas.draw_idle()
   1377 
   1378     def _pre_draw(self, framedata, blit):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

I do not get the error at all. I could not find good description for `canvas`. I was passing `fig` to the `save`, so it should not be a `None`.

Comment: I suppose you want to use `self.images.append([pc])` instead of `self.images.append([plt_im])`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest oh yes. It works with `[pc]` . The terminology of `image` and `artist` in documentation really confused me.

Comment: Where in the documentation does this confusion occur?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added the confusion of documentation in the question. Thanks for your help !